# Interruption of sound in bluetooth headphones, which is caused by dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Windows 10 on my laptop. And I have sound interruptions in my bluetooth headphones, which is caused by dual booting with Windows 10 (I know this, because when I had only Windows 10, there were no sound interruptions, but when I installed Ubuntu then audio interruptions started on Ubuntu and on Windows.) I hope I was able to describe my problem.

So, I hope you will help me!

P.S. I can't uninstall Windows or Ubuntu.

l

```
spci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb:
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak 2  7265 Combo /NON-vPro NGFF Combo Wireless-AC 7265
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It is not "caused by dual booting". So the question is wrong.

Comment: Hello! What it's caused by?

Comment: With Ubuntu it may be caused by 2.4 GHz and BT interference. But it can't affect Windows.

Comment: I didn't have sound cracking in Windows. But when I installed Ubuntu tnen cracking started

Comment: If it started both on Windows and Ubuntu, then it is a hardware problem.

Comment: And If it caused by 2.4 GHz and BT interference, can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I use my headphones and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi at the same time

Answer (score 1):

2.4 GHz and Bluetooth interference with Intel devices can be fixed in many cases by running:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

Reboot to apply.

This can be reverted by:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't help for me

Comment: The only reliable way is to use 5 GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: I used 5 GHz Wi-Fi and the problem wasn't solved

Comment: There are two locations where I used my headphones(there is 5 GHz Wi-Fi  in first location and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi in another)